# Ardunio Covert INT to Number

Tags: c++, arduino

Using Ardunio IDE

I have a RTC that returns separate ints for Hour / Minute / Second.

I want to create one number from all three of these Ints. I.E

Hour 12 / Min 11 / Second 50 would be:

121150

Help please?

Comment: converting to a string and then back again.

Comment: Come on, that's basic math. You just need to mupltiply first one by `10000`, second one by `100` and add all three.

Answer (score 0):

```
int h = 12;
int m = 11;
int s = 50;
int num = h * 10000 + m * 100 + s;
printf("%d\n", num);
```

Output: 121150